# How can i get the index of Scrollview item React-native?

Tags: react-native

this is my custom component code here..

```
const Item = (props) => {

  if (props.isFake) {
    return null
  }

  return (

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={styles.listItemParent}>
        {/*<Text style={styles.listItemText}> {props.index} </Text>*/}
        <Text style={styles.listItemText}> {props.title} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.listItemURL}> {props.url} </Text>
        {/*<Text>{props.lead}</Text>*/}
    </TouchableOpacity>

  )
};
```

and i render it like that...

```
<ScrollView>
 {this.state.items.map(item => <Item onPress={ (index)=> this.onclick(index)} {...item} />) }
</ScrollView>
```

How can i get the index of 'item'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.map returns the value and the **index** :)

```
<ScrollView>
 {this.state.items.map((item,i) => <Item onPress={ ()=> this.onclick(i)} {...item} />) }
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: oops i was try  
this.state.items.map(item,i => ...)
without () ! 
thx : )

Comment: so you can remember for other times, inside the map there is a anymous function (function only with paramters), how you give 2 paramters?  you give them with (a ,b)